# ReactJS + Redux: Why doesn't react-hot-loader work although installed?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hot-loader

I have the following dependencies installed:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.13.4",
    "react": "^15.1.0",
    "react-dom": "^15.1.0",
    "react-redux": "^4.4.5",
    "react-router": "^2.4.1",
    "redux": "^3.5.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.9.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^6.0.4",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.9.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.5.0",
    "babel-preset-react-hmre": "^1.1.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.5.0",
    "eslint": "^2.11.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^5.1.1",
    "react-hot-loader": "^1.3.0",
    "redux-logger": "^2.6.1",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.1.0",
    "webpack": "^1.13.1",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.6.1",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.10.0"
  }
}
```

The react-hot-loader used to work, where when I make a save to a change, it would reload automatically and update the application. But not it does not work anymore, so I would have to refresh the whole application manually to update it.

What could be causing the issue? How could I go about fixing it? Not sure if this would be source of the problem, but I switch on and off between two different projects, one being React Native and another being ReactJS. But after getting into React Native, the react-hot-loader on ReactJS just stopped working.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: some config problem

Answer (score 0):

react-native shouldn't affect the react-hot-loader in this project.

It's hard to tell without seeing any code as to get rhl to work the js needs to be created and rendered in the right way.

is this a server-side app or a client-side only app?  this has some bearing too.

I have an example app, [react-lego](https://github.com/peter-mouland/react-lego) which shows how to [add the latest version of react-hot-loader v3](https://github.com/peter-mouland/react-lego/compare/react-hot-loader)

hope it helps